# Could I ever go back to not using ReSharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

I have being using ReSharper (for C#) at work for about 2 years now. I am **really** missing ReSharper when I don't have it - could I ever go back to not using ReSharper?

Comment: Actually, I never got one with R# - and it sucks memory like crazy. I switched to Code Rush and am much happier.

Comment: I agree with Marc, It is slowwwwwwwww man!

Comment: ReSharper is great for beginners/novices because it gives suggestions on how to properly write your code (its like a high level, semantical compiler built into it). I love it (R# 7).

Comment: I agree, resharper is a productivity killer for anyone serious.

Comment: been coding for a long time.. tried resharper for a few days.. can't get used to it.. too obtrusive and seems to lose some auto complete features built into VS 2015.

Answer (score 6):

I don't miss it because I'm not using it.
Looks like I shouldn't start to use ReSharper because there is no way back?

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree. Coding without ReSharper is just not the same.

Answer (score -1):

You don't know what you have until you lose it. Yes, I will always need ReSharper.